# How to attach an XElement to a SMTP message as an attachment in C#

Tags: c#, xml, smtpclient

I'm trying to attach an XElement to an SMTP message i'm sending.

My code looks like this:

```
XElement xmlMsg = new XElement("Test",new XElement("TestSon", "DummyValue"),new XElement("TestSon2","DummyValue"));
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        byte[] contentAsBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(xmlMsg.ToString());
        memoryStream.Write(contentAsBytes, 0, contentAsBytes.Length);
        // Set the position to the beginning of the stream.

        memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        // Create attachment

        ContentType contentType = new ContentType();
        contentType.MediaType = MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain;
        contentType.Name = "Conversation.xml";
        Attachment attachment = new Attachment(memoryStream, contentType);
        mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
        Server.Send(mail);
    }
```

However, my email is received with the XML file clipped at the end, without the last 2 chars...

Am i missing something here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What encoding is `Encoding.Default` on your system?

If it is UTF-16 I expect the two bytes are a BOM which is (for some reason) not being included in the byte count.

Suggestions:

- Put `xmlMsg.ToString()` into a local variable, and check it in the debugger.
- Have a look at the bytes in `memoryStream`
- Look at the content of the email message in the raw, possibly copying the unencoded attachment so you can manually decode as a binary file.

Ie. check each step with as little automatic re-interpretation (eg. by an XML viewer) as possible.